# A Sequence at a forum register area

Tags: sequence

I want to register to a forum but stuck at a question to register.

Type the secuence 
GDB123_YTU

I tried 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,21,321
What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this just a really badly implemented Captcha?
I read this as they want you to type "GDB123_YTU" in.?
Maybe you have to add 4? So "GDB1234YTU". Is this really a valid question for SO?